# Avoiding node removal during optimization for preliminary estimation

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus

I'm doing a preliminary FPGA design where I want to establish whether I will be able to implement the pinout and clock routing -- basically I'm placing all the hard IP blocks and wiring up the clocks, but I'd like to add as little other logic as I can get away with at the moment.

The optimizer now very aggressively removes a lot of logic due to the undefined signals, and associated clocks and hard IP as well, which makes life a bit more difficult.

In previous designs, I've simply routed undefined inputs and outputs to pins, which forced the optimizer to leave them in, but this time I'm out of pins already.

I'd possibly construct a massive shift register and connect that to some pins, that would likely tell the optimizer that the values of those signals are unknown but defined -- is there a better way to implement "placeholder" logic?

The goal right now would be to lock down a resource plan, which would allow board design to begin as soon as it is clear whether external clock routing and buffers are necessary and pinout is finalized.

Comment: There must be RTL attributes or TCL script flags to suppress optimizations at different levels. Must be described in Quartus guide.

Comment: Here is a trick I use:  XOR all inputs together into one wire.  Connect that wire to all input pins of your internal blocks.  XOR all outputs of internal blocks into another wire and connect that to all device outputs.  This make all outputs and all internal circuitry a function of all inputs, and they will not be optimized away. You can wire up the clocks separately as you intend (or not, it's up to you).